# Creating Correlations

Tags: correlation

I have three variables, A, B, and C.  It seems obvious that if X = A-B and Y = C-B that there should be a correlation between X and Y.  When I've done this in matlab with random numbers, this seems to be the case with a mean r of about 0.5.  The fact that there is a correlation makes intuitive since because X and Y are sharing the variance in B; but when I've tried to figure out why it's 0.5, I've had less luck.  Any hints as to why this is the case would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried expliciting calculating $$\text{Cor}(X,Y)=\text{Cor}(A-B,C-B)=...$$?

Comment: Not sure If I follow your questions.  I've calculated three vectors of normally distributed random numbers, with a mean of 0 and std of 1, and calculated the equivalent of x and y.   Having done that 1000 times, the mean r value is .4992.  I've also done similar calculations with different means and stds (but not the extreme values Peter lists below).

Comment: You said that " This makes intuitive since, but when I've tried to figure out why this is the case, I've had less luck." so I was asking if you have actually done the paper and pencil calculations to see why the answer is the answer.

Comment: Other than running the correlations with random numbers, I haven't had luck trying to do any pencil and paper work with it.  I've tried to come up with some way of looking at it with the equations for correlations, but perhaps the reason that I haven't had any luck is because of the point Peter made below.

Comment: Correlation is scaled covariance, which is easier to work with: $$ {\rm cov}(A-B,C-B) = {\rm cov}(A,C) - {\rm cov}(A,B) - {\rm cov}(B,C) + {\rm var}(B) $$ Lots of different things can happen. E.g., if your variables are standardized and $A,C$ are uncorrelated and $B,C$ and $A,B$ each had a correlation of .5 (yes, that's a positive definite covariance matrix), then ${\rm cov}(A-B,C-B) = 0$. You can also make then nearly perfectly correlated when $A$ and $C$ are independent of $B$ and $B$ is on a much larger scale than $A,B$... As is, this question seems too broad. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: supposing that the std's of the three variables are on the same scale, why is it that r is about .5.

Comment: Check out my solution below

Comment: If you are generating independent standardized variables then, using the formula from my other comment, ${\rm cov}(A-B,C-B) = 1$. Correlation is defined as the covariance divided by the product of the standard deviations of the constituent variables. Each of $A-B$ and $C-B$ have standard deviation $\sqrt{2}$ (see, e.g. [this thread](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31177/does-the-variance-of-a-sum-equal-the-sum-of-the-variances)). Therefore the correlation is $1/(\sqrt{2} \cdot \sqrt{2}) = 1/2$. I guess that's your answer.

Comment: Suppose (perhaps unbeknownst to us) originally $A=X+B$ and $C=Y+B$ where $X,Y,B$ are *independent.* Then $X=A-B$ and $Y=C-B$ are as stipulated in the question but (assuming neither is constant) their correlation must be *zero* (not $1/2$) because $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Real insight into this question is afforded by pursuing @Macro's approach and computing $\text{Cov}(A-B,C-B)$ = $\text{Cov}(A,C)$ - $\text{Cov}(A,B)$ - $\text{Cov}(B,C)$ + $\text{Var}(B)$, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So calculating this by hand we have the following (I will assume independence of $A,B$ and $C$):

\begin{align*}
\text{Cor}(X,Y)&=\frac{\text{Cov}(X,Y)}{\sqrt{\text{Var(X)}\text{Var}(Y)}}\\
&\\
&=\frac{\text{Cov}(A-B,C-B)}{\sqrt{\text{Var}(A-B)\text{Var}(C-B)}}\\
&\\
&=\frac{E[(A-B)(C-B)]-E[A-B]E[C-B]}{\sqrt{[\text{Var}(A)+\text{Var}(B)]\times[\text{Var}(C)+\text{Var}(B)]}}\\
&\\
&=\frac{E[AC-AB -BC +B^2]-(E[A]-E[B])(E[C]-E[B])}{\sqrt{[\text{Var}(A)+\text{Var}(B)]\times[\text{Var}(C)+\text{Var}(B)]}}\\
&\\
&=\frac{E[AC]-E[AB] -E[BC] +E[B^2]-(E[A]-E[B])(E[C]-E[B])}{\sqrt{[\text{Var}(A)+\text{Var}(B)]\times[\text{Var}(C)+\text{Var}(B)]}}\\
&\\
&=\frac{E[A]E[C]-E[A]E[B] -E[B]E[C] +E[B^2]-(E[A]-E[B])(E[C]-E[B])}{\sqrt{[\text{Var}(A)+\text{Var}(B)]\times[\text{Var}(C)+\text{Var}(B)]}}\\
&\\
&=\frac{E[B^2]-(E[B])^2}{\sqrt{[\text{Var}(A)+\text{Var}(B)]\times[\text{Var}(C)+\text{Var}(B)]}}\\
&\\
&=\frac{\text{Var(B)}}{\sqrt{[\text{Var}(A)+\text{Var}(B)]\times[\text{Var}(C)+\text{Var}(B)]}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\times2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

Comment: +1 for the effort! You know you can use existing properties of covariance in your answers, right? ;) BTW, normality was not used anywhere in your answer.

Comment: Oh yes I do, but I wanted to make sure the OP understood doing everything by definition the long way.

Comment: Did I need to use normality somewhere?

Comment: No but you did specify that $A,B,C$ were normally distributed.

Comment: Oh that what just to show why I plugged in 0 and 1 where I did. I.e., I wanted to give a distribution to A,B and C so I could show what the expectation and variances were equal to, etc. I just chose standard normals because most of the `R` codes that came before used that.  Could have been any distribution really.

Comment: No biggie. Just pointing out that it seemed unnecessarily restrictive. The OP only specified that the variables were on the same scale (e.g. standardized).

Comment: I'd remove the normality. I think it confuses the issue

Comment: How would removing the normality influence things?

Comment: I got rid of the normality stuff.

Comment: @BabakP, this derivation still assumes $E(A)=E(B)=E(C)=0$ and that all variances are equal but those assumption aren't stated anywhere.

Comment: I did assume all variances are equal, but I did not assume E(A) = E(B) = E(C) = 0.  They all cancel out in the numerator if you factor out everything.  Unless you are talking about something else @Macro.

Comment: You're right. I didn't read carefully enough!

Comment: Does the assumption that all variances are equal influence anything other than the last two steps, where you assume the variance is 1?

Comment: Yes.  Assume the variances were all different numbers, plug them into the above formula and you won't get 1/2.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  The main thing I was wondering is if the assumption of equal variances influences early aspects of the equation.

Comment: Probably not of interest, but ran a simulation actually calculating the correlation in matlab and using the equation above (with the modifications that @John mentioned below for correlations between variables).  Mean r for actual correlations = .3923, mean r using equation was .3922.

Comment: Awesome, good to hear it validates.

Answer (score 3):

It will depend on what the variables are. E.g. (`R` code, should be pretty clear though)

```
set.seed(1234)
A <- rnorm(100)
B <- rnorm(100)
C <- rnorm(100)

cor(A-C, B-C) #0.40

A <- runif(100)
B <- runif(100)
C <- runif(100)

cor(A-C, B-C)  #0.54

A <- rnorm(100,1,10)
B <- rnorm(100,10,100)
C <- rnorm(100,1,200)

cor(A-C, B-C) #0.89
```

And, of course, if A and B are related, you would get other values

Comment: Good point, I've been using mean of 0 and std of 1.

Comment: Seems like the closer the two standard deviations of A and C are, the closer the mean of r is to .5

Comment: It should be possible to derive the expected correlation given the distributions.... but it's not the sort of thing I know how to do!

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what happens is that you have two sources of variance in your subtracted score and one of those sources is shared between each of the subtracted scores. When the initial random variables of `A`, `B`, and `C` are all independent but you then add in the variance from `B` to both `A`, and `C` then the proportion of variance that's shared is going to be your correlation. You had equal variances in each condition, that's why it's 0.5, half of the variance is shared.

Note that, if the correlation between `A` and `B` is 0 then the `var(A-B) == var(A) + var(B)`. All of the following equations show similar results (I'll get to why not exact later).

```
a <- rnorm(10000, 0, 1)
b <- rnorm(10000, 0, 1)
var(a)
var(b)
var(a) + var(b)
var(a + b)
var(a - b)
```

So, your `X`, and `Y` variables you created include the variance from `B`. Correlations are about shared variance so your intuitions are correct.

I imagine that you've already done something like the following but perhaps through brute force. I'm using R and the `mvrnorm` function because it allows me to set my initial correlations to 0.

```
library(MASS) #so I can use mvrnorm and insure 0 correlation

# The following is a covariance matrix with the variance of each condition
# on the diagonal and the covariances among the conditions of of it.
sigma <- matrix(c(1.0, 0.0,  0.0,
                  0.0, 1.0,  0.0,
                  0.0, 0.0,  1.0), 3, byrow = TRUE)
mat <- mvrnorm(100, c(0,0,0), sigma, empirical = TRUE)
cor(mat)
a <- mat[,1]
b <- mat[,2]
c <- mat[,3]

x <- a - b
y <- c - b

cor(x, y)
```

You can see the final correlation of `x` and `y` is 0.5, just as you found. You can predict in advance what would happen if you changed the variances of the conditions (keep in mind variance is what matters here, not standard deviation). Let's say the variance of `b` was raised from 1 to 2. Now, the proportion of variance that comes from `b` in `x` is going to be `var(b) / (var(a) + var(b))` or 2/3. That's going to be the same for `y` so the geometric mean shared variance is going to be equal to both of those and the correlation is 0.66 (2/3). To generate the data you'd just change the original variance-covariance matrix I made above and then proceed as above.

```
# note the variance of the second condition is now 2
sigma <- matrix(c(1.0, 0.0,  0.0,
                  0.0, 2.0,  0.0,
                  0.0, 0.0,  1.0), 3, byrow = TRUE)
mat <- mvrnorm(100, c(0,0,0), sigma, empirical = TRUE)
....
```

And, indeed, what happens is you get a correlation of 0.66. So, it's easy to work out what the correlation should be based on the initial variances. If you've got correlations among `a`, `b`, and `c`, and you almost always do, then it becomes a bit trickier. I imagine you've come across this in your simulations when you said that what you found was approximately 0.5. Sometimes your random variables happened to be correlated. If I take my current variables that are uncorrelated then the following will all produce the same results.

```
var(a) + var(b)
var(a - b)
var(a + b)
```

They all show the sum of the variances. But the equations are different if there is a correlation. The first one should be...

```
var(a) + var(b) - 2*cov(a,b)
```

And it would be the same as `var(a) + var(b)` when the correlation is 0. It also comes out the same as `var(a - b)`. As an aside, you actually have to add the covariance term instead of the subtracting to match `var(a + b)`.

So, hopefully that explains it in enough detail that you could derive the expected correlation of `X` and `Y` based on the covariances among `A`, `B`, and `C`, and their respective variances.

There's a graphical explanation using geometry that's very pretty but it escapes me right now. Also, this is excellent stuff to understand if you ever want to get a grasp on multiple regression (or even unbalanced ANOVAs).

Comment: Suppose the variance in A and C is not equal.  How would one work out what the correlation would be based on the initial variance then?

Comment: sorry, I'm still not getting it yet.  Maybe I've just been thinking about it too much today.

Comment: Here's a simple equation for when the initial correlations are 0. Let's say I made the initial variances a = 6, b = 2, c = 1.5. The proportion of shared variance calculation is still the same for x where the proportion shared variance is var(a)/(var(a) + var(b)) or 6/8. For y it would be 2/3.5. To find out their correlation you have to get the geometric mean of those shared variances sqrt(2/8 * 2/3.5). (You'd have to correct the initial shared variances by the covariance if the a, b, c values were correlated.)

Comment: You could try it by applying my calculation to Pete Flom's last example and you'll get the correct answer. (remember to change the SD's to variances).

Answer (score -2):

Nope. Let $B=C$, let $A=B$, or let $C=A$.

Comment: Could you further elaborate?

Comment: If $B=C$, then $Y=0$ and $\mbox{cor}(X, 0) = 0$. Stating the assumptions behind this problem *would* have given the OP some intuition about his question.

Comment: If $Y=0$ then $\text{cor}(X,0)$ is undefined, not 0.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that to be `cov`. Nonetheless, stating some assumptions behind this will help everyone understand the problem.

Comment: I agree with that statement

Comment: +1.  Generally, I find simple counterexamples to be far more revealing than, say, ten lines of obscure equations or several dozen lines of code.