# Sum of variances law

Tags: distributions, variance

I am currently trying to grasp the concept of Variance Sum Law where

```
variance(x + y) = variance(x) + variance(y)
```

I am not even sure if I understand it correctly so I tried to do a little practical example.

Correct me where my reasoning is wrong.

For 2 independent variables & values the calculated variance is as follows:

for measurements of x [9,5,13] variance = 10.67
for measurements of y [1,14, 2] variance = 34.89

Now according the law I would expect for:

[10 (9+1) , 19 (5 + 14) , 15 (13 +2)] variance = 10.67 + 34.89 but after putting it to variance calculator I get the value 13.56.

Seems I am totally not getting what this is about. Can you show me where is my reasoning bad?

Comment: I don't understand your notation. Can you format your question a little better? Also, the second number in the sum should be `29`.

Comment: That would be a problem since I am just beginning with statistics and do not now the standard notation.

Comment: What is the wording of the law you're using?

Comment: You are looking at a finite dataset & the correlation between these 2 vectors is not 0.

Comment: Probably relevant: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31177/

Comment: Please tell us how you know the two variables are independent.  (One necessary condition is that their covariance be zero: what is the covariance?)

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, $\text{Var}(X + Y) = \text{Var}(X) + \text{Var}(Y)$ only holds for $X$ and $Y$ uncorrelated, but you're pairing them in a systematic way which isn't expected to give zero correlation.  Try pairing each value from the set $x$ with every value from the set $y$, taking the sum and then find the variance of this distribution.