# What is my missing assumption is sum of variances?

Tags: variance, proof

In [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31177/does-the-variance-of-a-sum-equal-the-sum-of-the-variances), it says that in general the sum of the variances is not equal to the variance of the sum.

I tried to work it out by myself, and I think I got a different result, namely that the variance of the sum is equal to the sum of the variances. Do I have incorrect work here for random variables in general? Am I missing some assumption I made?

\begin{eqnarray*}
Var(X+Y) & = & E[(X+Y)^{2}]-(E[X+Y])^{2}\\
 & = & E[X^{2}+Y^{2}+XY]-(E[X]+E[Y])^{2}\\
 & = & E[X^{2}]+E[Y^{2}]+E[XY]-(E[X])^{2}-(E[Y])^{2}-E[X]E[Y]\\
 & = & E[X^{2}]-(EX)^{2}+E[Y^{2}]-(EY)^{2}\\
 & = & Var(X)+Var(Y)
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: You also miss something here $E[(X+Y)^2]=E(X^2+2XY+Y^2)$. Your case is correct only when $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: @DeepNorth You're saying that equation in your comment is only true when X and Y are independent??

Comment: Yes, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$ then the  $Cov(X,Y)=0$

Comment: @DeepNorth Ok. I see how $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$ implies uncorrelatedness ( I think that's the definition of uncorrelatedness...), but I don't understand how $E[(X+Y)^2]=E(X^2+2XY+Y^2)$ implies $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$. The former equation seems like it's just basic algebra. Am I wrong, or misinterpreting something?

Comment: It is not from $E[(X+Y)^2]=E(X^2+2XY+Y^2)$ it is an assumption you have to make.

Comment: Clarification.  $E[XY] = E[X]E[Y]$ is not *only* true when $X$ and $Y$ are independent, it just *is* true when they are independent.  It's not an if and only if.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your third line, you implicitly assume the relation

$$E[XY] - E[X]E[Y] = 0$$

and use it to cancel the cross term.  This relation is untrue for general $X$ and $Y$.  Note that if it *were* true, it would follow that

$$ E[X^2] = E[X \times X] = E[X]E[X] = E[X]^2 $$

and all the other terms in your relation would also cancel.  So, under your implicit assumption, you've actually shown that

$$ Var(X + Y) = 0 $$

Which I don't think I have to convince you is untrue.

Note that, given the general failure of

$$ E[XY] - E[X]E[Y] = 0 $$

it pays to *measure* it's failure for any given two random variables.  This leads to the definition of **covariance**

$$ Cov(X, Y) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y] $$