# How to add up partial confidence intervals to create a total confidence interval?

Tags: probability, confidence-interval

I have a response variable that obtains different confidence intervals (CI) when calculated with different explanatory variables. I want to add up all values of the response variable and create a CI for the sum.

I would understand how to do if someone please helped me solve the following example from a triathlon where time (minutes) is the response variable, and distance (km) and discipline are the explanatory variables:

- The 95% CI for swimming 1.5 km is 40 to 50 minutes
- The 95% CI for cycling 40 km is 60 to 80 minutes
- The 95% CI for running 10 km is 30 to 40 minutes

Q: Between how long does it take a person to complete the triathlon with a 95% CI?

[If it makes any difference, I assuming normal distribution and independence between disciplines]

Thank you

Comment: Are these really *confidence* intervals?  The concept does not usually apply to the results of a single individual: it pertains to estimates of a *population.*  What, then, do these intervals actually mean and how have you computed them?  This is a crucial point because it's likely the intervals are based on correlated data, which requires a different method of combination than if they were independent intervals.

Comment: @whuber
Thank you for your comment, I have changed the question so it considers a population instead. Unfortunately i don't know how the CI were calculated.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  Since now it's likely the data are (highly) correlated--a good athlete typically has lower times and a poorer athlete has higher times--then the root-sum-of-squares method is sure to overstate the CI.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In short:

- Take as central point of your confidence interval the sum of central points of every confidence interval (45+70+35=150 minutes).
- Take as radius of your interval the square root of the sum of the squares of the radius of every confidence interval $\sqrt{5^2+10^2+5^2}=12.25$

Therefore, a person does that triathlon in between 137.75 and 162.25 minutes with 95% probability. Anyway, beware of assumptions.

In long:

I assumed normal distribution and independence between disciplines, although first assumption may be reasonable as a rough approximation but second assumption is likely false, because I would expect that people performing well in one discipline are likely to perform well on the other ones (for example, I would expect myself to perform poorly in every discipline in a triathlon).

Assuming that times in every discipline is a normal variable, total time is just the sum of three random variables, and therefore normally distributed. Variance of the sum is also the sum of variances of the three variables, and since intervals radius is proportional to the square root of variance, you can just sum the squares of radius of every interval to get the square of the radius of the sum variable.

However, please notice that the (dubious) assumption that times for each discipline are independent narrows the resulting interval - I would say, unrealistically narrows it.

We could make the opposite assumption, that is that times for disciplines are absolutely correlated (that is, roughly, that the person who swam in 40 minutes is the same that cycled in 60 minutes and ran in 30 minutes). That assumption is probably as unrealistic as the assumption of independence was, but surely not a lot more unrealistic.

In this assumption, the radius of intervals just sum, and the triathlon is expected to be completed in between 130 and 170 minutes by 95% of athletes.

In the end, we should expect the real interval to be somewhere between [137.25,162.25] and [130,170] (both unrealistic extreme cases), but to give a more accurate result we would need to know (at least) what is the correlation between times in different discipline.

**Edit** after reviewing the answer a few years later: The assumption I made that results in different disciplines are likely positively correlated is reasonable if the sample includes people with different levels of fitness. However, if the sample only includes people with similar overall level in triathlon - for example, triathletes who took part in the 2020 Olympic Games - correlation between disciplines might be negative. Anyway, since assuming negative correlation yields smaller confidence intervals (or even zero length intervals), in case of lack of information about correlation I would take the conservative assumption that correlation is somewhere between 0 and 1. *End of edit.*

### Edit about terminology

As Whuber points in his comments, it's not clear what is the meaning of the intervals given in the question. Although, the answer is valid interpreting the resulting intervals in the same way of the intervals in the question.

The two reasonable meanings of the intervals of the question are:

- Intervals of confidence about the mean of each sport.
- Or intervals containing the times of 95% of participants on each sport.

In spite of the wording of the question fitting better the second meaning (and hence the wording in my answer), the name "confidence interval" is usually not used with this meaning.

However, since individual times follow a normal distribution (according to assumption made in the question) and estimations of means also follow a normal distribution (if sample size is large enough or if we keep sticking to the assumption that individual times are normally distributed), the arithmetic of intervals is the same for both meanings and therefore the results given hold for both meanings.

Comment: The final confidence interval could have zero length: it's plausible that the times are strongly negatively correlated and that this particular athlete might have consistent total times but variable split times during the race.  Thus, we can't say much of anything until we understand just what these intervals actually are and how they were computed.

Comment: If we assumed correlation +1 between swimming and running and correlation -1 between other times, the interval would be zero length. Anyway, I think we can reasonably assume that correlation between times are somewhere 0 and 1, and I took those values as extreme values, but for some other variables in other problems, intervals of sum could be smaller than for each individual variable.

Comment: I don't think we will need to assume anything.  Because these are "response" variables, what we need to do is find out how the CIs were computed.  (Likely they are based on a common set of predictor variables.) Then we will be in a better position to make reasonable recommendations about how to combine them, rather than having to speculate.

Comment: @Pere
Thank you for a very comprehensive response. Unfortunately i don't know how the CIs were calculated. but I can assume that the correlation will be between 0 and +1, so I will use your example with the two extremes.

Comment: "A person does that triathlon in between 137.75 and 162.25 minutes with 95% probability" is likely not to be understood in a way that is consistent with a confidence interval.  Remember, a confidence interval is a statement about *an average in a population,* not about any particular or random individual. Consider an analogous, but simpler, situation in which you are estimating the average number of testicles in a human population. Would you seriously write something like "a person has between 0.95 and 1.05 testicles with 95% probability"?

Comment: If we a seriously assumed that the number of testicles follows a normal distribution, we could seriously write something like "a person has between 0.95 and 1.05 testicles with 95% probability" (but of course number of testicles doesn't follow a normal distribution, although it can be assumed that sporting times do).

Comment: @Whuber: Testicle jokes aside, as you pointed in your first question it's not clear what are those intervals are. They might be confidence intervals of the mean or they might be intervals containing 95% of probability for times. Anyway, the maths about those intervals work for both cases, and the compound intervals at the end should be interpreted with the same meaning as the original intervals of the question. I see that I mixed both meanings in the wording of my answer, but I'm not sure how much it hurts its understability.

Comment: The *sampling distribution of the mean* number of testicles *does* follow a normal distribution, very closely.  Your comment is bizarre because it's so obviously wrong to say what you wrote: indeed, with 99+% probability, people have either zero or two testicles.  That disconnect between what you write and what is so obviously true hurts understandability.

Comment: I understand your point that since we do know what the intervals given in the question mean, we can't tell what the intervals in the result mean. But since, according to the question "A group of people swims 1.5 km in between 40 and 50 minutes with a 95% CI", whatever it means, the answer should be "The group does that triathlon in between 137.75 and 162.25 minutes with a 95% CI", with the same meaning. Anyway, whatever it means, I agree that it is a bizarre way to express such a meaning.

Comment: I hope my last edit can make the question clear enough.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the careful discussion of assumptions and the additional remarks on the meanings of the words.

Comment: What if you knew the correlations between the random variables, which is easy enough to figure out based on the same days used to produce the confidence intervals?

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist - That would warrant a different question, and its anwer would be based on the answers to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31177/does-the-variance-of-a-sum-equal-the-sum-of-the-variances

Answer (score 0):

Pere has given a good answer. Adding up of variances is what happens when you add distributions. However in your case, he has assumed the radius as the standard deviation. but in fact, it is 1.96 times the standard deviation. So you will need to divide the radius (pere's terminology) by 1.96 (95% conf int) and then square, sum and take sq-root.

Comment: Please beware that I'm not assuming the radius to be the standard deviation. Dividing by 1.96 (with additional assumptions) would be useful to find the standard deviation, but to find the radius of the CI for the sum, you need to square the radius, sum and take the square root. That is, the square root of the sum of squared standard deviations is the standard deviation of the sum, and doing the same operations on the radius yields the radius of the sum - which is what is the question is about.

Comment: The original CI radius (i.e. 5, 10 and 5) are nothing but 1.96*std-deviation of the distribution they came from.... So, you will need to divide them by 1.96 and then square and sum before taking the square root again. 
i.e. 
SQ_ROOT((5/1.96)^2 + (10/1.96)^2 +(5/1.96)^2) will be the standard deviation of the added distributions..... 
And you need to multiply this by 1.96 again to get the radius of the final CI..... And that happens to be the same number you have arrived at.... :) 
So I just arrived this by a more purer way :)