# Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution

Using the normal distribution. Let $X\sim  \mathcal{N}(1, 2)$ and $Y\sim \mathcal{N}(2, 3)$ where $\mathcal{N}(μ, \sigma^2$)
denotes the normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. X and Y are
independent. Let $U = 2X + 3Y$.

What is the mean of U?
What is the variance of U?
What is $P(6<=U<=7.5)$?

For the mean of U, I calculated $2(1)+3(2)=8$. For the variance of U I calculated $ 2(2)+3(3)=13$.

Then I found `pnorm(7.5,mean=8,sd=sqrt13)-pnorm(6,mean=8,sd=sqrt13)`
[1] 0.1553036
for P(6<=U<=7.5).

Did I do this correctly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I vote to close this as a duplicate. Did you read @Corone's [edited answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/50581/6633) to your [other question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/31328/6633)?

Comment: Yes, I did. But this question has the U=2x+3Y involved. Also, I did not get a confirmation that my 67% was correct? If it is possible, could you verify that I took the correct course of action?