# Finding the probability X > Y

Tags: probability

I am curious on how to find the probability a random variable X is greater than Y (given their means and variance, and also that they are independent.)
I stumbled across this post: [probability of one random variable being greater than another](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50501/probability-of-one-random-variable-being-greater-than-another?newreg=83c2e76227cc4389887e976907a10cd0)
but am unsure how to answer this question with not necessarily normal distributions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get a general answer, knowing just the mean, variance, and that $X$ and $Y$ are independent will not suffice to know this probability. Consider the following example. If $X,Y$ are both $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, so mean 0 and variance 1, then $P(X>Y) = \frac12$. On the other hand, suppose $X$ and $Y$ are both distributed to have equal probability of being $\pm 1$. Such an $X,Y$ pair will also have mean 0 and variance 1, but now, $P(X>Y) = P(X=1,Y=-1)= \frac14$ (otherwise, it is either the case that $X=Y$ or $-1 = X < Y = 1$).

The general formula for calculating $P(X>Y)$ when $X$ and $Y$ are independent will depend on the respective distributions $F_X$ and $F_Y$ of $X$ and $Y$. A number of equivalent formulae are
$$\begin{aligned}\int P(Y < x)\,\mathrm dF_X(x) &= \int_{-\infty}^x\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm dF_X(x)\mathrm dF_Y(y) \\&= \int_y^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm dF_Y(y)\mathrm dF_X(x) = \int P(X>y)\,\mathrm dF_Y(y)\end{aligned}$$
Clearly, you will not get an analytic solution except in very special cases like when $Y$ and $X$ have nice formulas for their CDFs like in the normal case.

Answer (score 4):

$$P(X > Y) = P(X-Y > 0)  = 1-P(X-Y \leq 0)$$

So this problem is equivalent to finding the cumulative distribution function $F(Z \leq z)$ with $Z = X + (-Y)$, for the value $z=0$.

- The general expression for the distribution function of a sum of two variables is a convolution $$P(X-Y \leq z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x) F_Y(z+x) dx$$
- In special cases the integral has a closed form and often you can look up the solution.

  In particular a [stable distribution family](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution), which is closed under addition, will have a way to describe the distribution of a linear sum (but the normal distribution is the only case which has finite variance).

  The difference between two Poisson distributions is a [Skellam distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution)

  The difference between two Gamma distributions is often more difficult. [Difference of Gamma random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48378/) bit special cases like the [pdf of the difference of two exponentially distributed random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115022/pdf-of-the-difference-of-two-exponentially-distributed-random-variables) is simple.

  The difference between two t-distributions is a special case of the [Behrens-Fisher distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behrens%E2%80%93Fisher_distribution).
- If you *only* know the variance and means then you can not find an exact distribution, but you could find bounds using [limits for inequalities](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_inequality) which come in several forms (which one to use depends on your situation and goal).