# How to calculate the probability distribution F(X,Y) when the distributions of X and Y are known?

Tags: probability, random-variable, function

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are normally distributed with known means and standard deviations. How do I calculate what is the probability distribution some function $f(X,Y)$? For example, say $f(X,Y)=2X+Y$. How does one do this kind of computations?

Comment: Hint: What is the distribution of the sum of two Gaussian random variables? Is it not a Gaussian, as well ?

Comment: As @Mark noted, there is not sufficient information to define the $f(X,Y)$. You need to know something about the relation between $X$ and $Y$. A common assumption would be independence, which would allow full characterization $f(X,Y)$. If this assumption is allowed, I would suggest editing the post to reflect this.

Comment: @kaka No. In general the sum of 2 Gaussian random variables is not Gaussian as well. If X and Y are Bivariate Normal, then the sum of X and Y is Gaussian, but in general not. This is a common fallacy.

Comment: What if $Y = - 2 X$?  When you want to answer a very general question that may not really have one it's usually a good strategy to try to come up with simple counterexamples.

Answer (score 2):

There is insufficient information to make calculations f(X,Y).  The dependency, if any, between X and Y determines their joint distribution, and hence any function of X and Y.  See my answer and   Glen_b's comment to my answer at [Distribution for an operation of variables with identical distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158243/distribution-for-an-operation-of-variables-with-identical-distributions/158345#158345) .

If it is known that X and Y are jointly Normal, i.e., Bivariate Normal, then calculations could be made if you also know the correlation coefficient between X and Y, or equivalently since means and standard deviations are known, cov(X,Y).  If X and Y are Bivariate Normal, you can use the formulas in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution for the case n = 2.  In particular, if X and Y are Bivariate Normal, then X + 2*Y is Normal, and E(2*X + Y) = 2*E(X) + E(Y), and Var(2*X + Y) = 4*Var(X) + Var(Y) + 4*Cov(X,Y).